# Never datatype in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have been going through the documentation of Typescript and came across the datatype Never, so far I couldn't exactly figure out what they are trying to imply in the sentence ,
// Function returning never must have unreachable end point

```
function infiniteLoop(): never {
    while (true) {
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says that if you specify never as the return type, the return statement of the function must not be reachable.
For example the function will always throw an error, or there's an infinite loop somewhere.

It's easily to visualize this if we rewrite the example like this:

```js
function infiniteLoop(): never {
    while (true) {
    }
    return 'this will never execute';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never is information that this particular part shouldn't be reachable. For example in your code, you have an infinite loop and we don't want to iterate infinite loop. Simply as that.

But a real question is how can it be useful for us?
It might be helpful for instance while creating more advanced types to point **what they are not**

for example, let's declare our own NonNullable type:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

Here we are checking if T is null or undefined. If it is then we are pointing that it should never happen. Then while using this type:

```
let value: NonNullable<string>;
value = "Test";
value = null; // error
```